# Emacs in a Debian 8 chroot environment?

Tags: debian, emacs, chroot

I'm working with a Debian maintainer on a failed self test for a software package under ARMEL. The maintainer was kind enough to help me duplicate his environment.

When I attempt to add `http://ftp.debian.org/debian unstable main` to the local `sources.list`, I get an error:

```
root@debian-8:/# find ./ -name sources.list
./usr/share/doc/apt/examples/sources.list
./etc/apt/sources.list
root@debian-8:/# emacs ./etc/apt/sources.list
bash: emacs: command not found
```

Within the environment, I cannot perform a `apt-get install emacs` due to a lame `sources.list`. I also exited `chroot` and added the source to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, but it was not carried over or made available to the `chroot` environment.

The host is Debian-8, x86_64, fully patched.

How do I add emacs to the chroot environment?

---

```
# apt-get install qemu-user-static debootstrap
# qemu-debootstrap --arch=armel --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg \
  --variant=buildd --exclude=debfoster unstable debian-armel http://ftp.debian.org/debian
# chroot debian-armel
# apt-get install devscripts
[add 'deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian unstable main' to /etc/apt/sources.list]
# cd
# apt-get update && apt-get source libcrypto++
# cd libcrypto++-*
# debuild
```

Comment: Can't you just install it in your chroot? If you do not have `emacs` to update your sources list, you can also use `nano` or `vi`, the first one being especially easy to use

Comment: @Marius - *"Can't you just install it in your chroot?"* - you kinda replied to my question with the question I asked :)

Comment: Well, not **all** I meant. **1** How short is your sources list? **2** Do you have nano or vi available?

Comment: @Marius - ***1***: Oh, my bad. I thought you meant *"Can't you just install it [emacs] in your chroot"*. ***2***: I'm not sure about `nano` or `vi`. I don't use either one, so its does not matter in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you do not know how to use alternative editors like `vi` or `nano`. Hence, inside your chroot:

1. First try directly installing emacs,

   ```
      apt-get install emacs
   ```

   If this works, fine. Otherwise:
2. Copy your current `sources.list` out of the way:

   ```
    cd /etc/apt
    cp sources.list sources.list.old
   ```
3. Now let us build a new `sources.list` :

   ```
    cat "deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free" > sources.list

    cat "deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free" >> sources.list

    cat "deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free" >> sources.list

    cat "deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-proposed-updates main contrib non-free" >> sources.list

    cat "deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free" >> sources.list
   ```

Please do not confuse `>>` with `>`. Also, please notice this is for the **current Debian stable**, a.k.a jessie. Should you wish any other version, like wheezy or unstable, you will have to substitute for `jessie` in the commands above the name of the version you have installed.

4. Now we are ready:

   ```
    apt-get update
    apt-get install emacs
   ```

Comment: Thanks Marius. It was even easier once I found out where the jailed environment was: a simple `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /root/debian-armel/etc/apt/sources.list`. I could not perform it earlier because I could not find the jailed environment when looking under `/var` and `/opt`. Plus, I was trying to `find` the wrong name because I was looking for *`jail`*. (If you can't tell, I usually work with real hardware, and not cross-chroot'd environments). Thanks again.